# How to make shape not to go to GameOver? -SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where there is a square shape and every time the player taps on the square, it goes to GameOver scene. All I want to do is when the square shape is tapped, it will be allotted different position of the screen to be tapped on the squares.

> Here is my code:

```
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)




   if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        //The first ball that shows up
        if name == "startball"
        {
            print("Touched", terminator: "")
             addBall(ballSize)




            self.addChild(score)
        }
        else if name == "shape"{

            scoreCount += 1

           addBall(ballSize)




            audioPlayer.play()

        }  





    }



    else {

        let scene =  GameOver(size: self.size)
        scene.setMyScore(0)
        let skView = self.view! as SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        scene.setMessage("You Lost!")

        scene.setEndGameMode(va)
        gameTimer.invalidate()
        shownTimer.invalidate()
        print(" timers invalidated ", terminator: "")
        ran = true
        skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.25))
    }








    if firstTouch {
        shownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.decTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TIME_INCREMENT, target:self, selector: Selector("endGame"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        firstTouch = false



    }

    if touchCount > 5 {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let skView = self.view! as SKView
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            var scene: Congratz!
            scene =  Congratz(size: skView.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0))



        }




    }
    touchCount += 1



}




    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    super.update(currentTime)




}

func endGame(){
    shownTimer.invalidate()
    gameTimer.invalidate()
    let scene =  GameOver(size: self.size)
    scene.setMyScore(scoreCount)
    if let skView = self.view {
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        scene.setMessage("Times up")

        skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0.25))
    }

}







       override func addBall(_ size: Int) {
      // Add the ball
      let currentBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(size))

    let viewMidX = view!.bounds.midX
    let viewMidY = view!.bounds.midY

    currentBall.fillColor = pickColor()



    currentBall.position = randomBallPosition()




    if scoreCount != 0{
        if scoreCount == 1{
            self.addChild(score)
            self.addChild(timeLeftLabel)
            self.childNode(withName: "welcome")?.removeFromParent()
        }
        self.childNode(withName: "ball")?.run(getSmaller)
        self.childNode(withName: "ball")?.removeFromParent()

    }
     currentBall.name = "ball"


    self.addChild(currentBall)
}

     func addSquare(_ size: Int) {
    // Add the square
    let shape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width:CGFloat(size), height:CGFloat(size)))

    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 64, y: 64, width: 160, height: 160), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath

    shape.fillColor = pickColor()

    shape.position = randomBallPosition()

    shape.name = "shape"

    self.addChild(shape)

} 


    func randomBallPosition() -> CGPoint {
    let xPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((view?.bounds.maxX)! + 1)))
    let yPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((view?.bounds.maxY)! + 1)))


    return CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest would be to make something like an `enum` for the different shapes, so you can keep track of what shape you're using.

```
enum GameShape: Int {

    case circle = 0
    case square = 1

}
```

Then create a `GameShape` property at the top of your `GameScene`:

```
var currentShape: GameShape = .circle
```

Then you could create some sort of `updateShape` method, which you could call in your `touchesBegan` method instead of just `addBall`

```
func updateShape(shapeSize: CGSize) {

    switch currentShape {
        case .circle:
            addCircle(shapeSize)
        case .square:
            addSquare(shapeSize)
        default:
            break
    }

    // However you want to setup the condition for changing shape
    if (condition) {
        currentShape = .square
    }

}

func addBall(_ size: CGSize) {
    // Add the ball
}

func addSquare(_ size: CGSize) {
   // Add the square
}
```

Now in your `touchesBegan` method, instead of calling `addBall(size`, you could call `updateShape`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>!, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // Setup your code for detecting position for shape origin
    updateShape(shapeSize)

}
```

**EDIT** - Your code is a mess. You really should take the time to make sure it's properly formatted when you submit it, otherwise it's really hard to help you. Indentation helps to see where a closure begins and ends. From what I can tell, it looks like you have two or more functions nested within your `addBall` method. This is not good. I tried my best to clean it up for you. You'll still need to write the code to make the shape a square, but I've lead you in the right direction to start to make that happen:

```
func addBall(_ size: CGSize) {
    // Add the ball
    let currentBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(size))

    let viewMidX = view!.bounds.midX
    let viewMidY = view!.bounds.midY

    currentBall.fillColor = pickColor()

    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 64, y: 64, width: 160, height: 160), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath

    shape.fillColor = pickColor()

    currentBall.position = randomBallPosition()
    shape.position = randomBallPosition()

    self.addChild(shape)

    if scoreCount != 0{
        if scoreCount == 1{
            self.addChild(score)
            self.addChild(timeLeftLabel)
            self.childNode(withName: "welcome")?.removeFromParent()
        }
        self.childNode(withName: "ball")?.run(getSmaller)
        self.childNode(withName: "ball")?.removeFromParent()

    }
    currentBall.name = "ball"
    shape.name = "ball"

    self.addChild(currentBall)
}

func addSquare(_ size: CGSize) {
    // Add the square
}

func randomBallPosition() -> CGPoint {
    let xPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((view?.bounds.maxX)! + 1)))
    let yPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((view?.bounds.maxY)! + 1)))


    return CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)

}
```

Now the above code assumes you have some property named `shape` because from what I could tell you never explicitly instantiated that, but you begin manipulating it.

Comment: the addSquare, it gets me an error: "use of local variable addSquare before its declaration. "

Comment: @D.W - Maybe you could show the code you used to implement it? Because `addSquare` is a function, not a variable - so I think maybe you're syntax is wrong

Comment: @D.W - Recommendation: edit your code so that it's properly formatted. We use indentation for a reason, it helps us see what's going on within a certain block of code, and where brackets begin and end. I can't tell what's going on in your code because everything is aligned to the left. From what I can tell, it looks like you have the `addSquare` method within the `addBall` method, and you close out the `addBall` method with a `}` before you even start to execute the code. I just added those as an example. You need to actually write the code for the methods

Comment: @D.W - You shouldn't have functions nested within other functions. It looks like you put your `randomBallPosition` function and the `addSquare` function inside your `addBall` function.

Comment: @D.W - I did my best to clean up your code. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Hey @Pierce, can you check out my updated question. I have applied the addSquare() part, but can you check if everything right

Comment: @D.W - It looks okay from what I can tell, it's hard to really say without running it. Have you run it? What is the result? Why are you drawing a path for the square shape? Is that even necessary?

Comment: Hey, can you check out my updated question? If you have any clue why it is happening.

Comment: @D.W - It looks to me like you say `if let name = touchedNode.name {} else { gameOver }` - So I would assume that your `touchedNode.name` is equal to `nil` which is causing it call your block of code for the game over.

Comment: Is there way you can fix this by showing an example prior to my code above?

Comment: @D.W - It's really hard to do that, I mean I'm not intimately acquainted with your project. Maybe for now get rid of that `else` statement until you figure out a way to setup your project so that all your nodes have the proper name when you need them to.